# Convergence in $L_p(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I tried to examine a sequence for convergence in $L_p(\mathbb{R}), \> 1 \leq p < \infty$:

\begin{equation*}
g_n(t) = \dfrac{3^{-|t|}}{1+|t-n|}
\end{equation*}

It is obvious that it converges to 0 as n tends to infinity.

\begin{equation*}
g_n(t) \to 0 \text{ as }n \to \infty
\end{equation*}

The last part was to find the limit of $||g_n - 0||$ as $n \to \infty$, basically:

\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\dfrac{3^{-|t|}}{1+|t-n|}\right)^pdt \to \bigg| g_n \to 0,\> |g_n(t)| \leq 3^{-|t|}, 3^{-|t|} \in L_p(\mathbb{R}) \bigg| \to \int_{\mathbb{R}}0dt = 0, \> n \to \infty
\end{equation*}

Is it correct to examine convergence for given example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $g_n$ point-wisely converge to zero, but this is not sufficient to say that its integral converges to zero. You would like to first use Dominated Convergence Theorem to say the limiting integral exist, and then use point-wise convergence to say the integral is 0.